# how to filter s3 notifications per object prefix from bucket that contains several subfolders

Tags: amazon-s3

I'm using s3 for storage and it's contains bucket that contains several subfolders

for example:

mybucket/root

mybucket/root/sub1

mybucket/root/sub2

mybucket/root/sub2/sub3/sub4/sub5

each folders can contains s3 object's, but i want to notify into sqs only files that start with prefix "p"

i've set prefix "p*", but now it's filters all files.

should it be set for all the prefix for all direcories?
can i set it for just object's, ignoring the directories prefix?
i.e prefix only for the files?

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In S3, within a bucket, the namespace is actually flat.  The `/` appearing in object keys is used to emulate folder structure, but the structure is not really there, and S3 treats the object keys in most cases as a single string, and not as path + filename.

The event filter rules are a case where the entire object key is being used, so it's only possible to specify matching by prefix or suffix of the *entire* key -- path + filename.

If you have multiple "directories" In the root of the bucket, e.g. `foo/` and `bar/` and you want to find objects where the next character after the `/` delimiter is `p` then you would need a rule matching the prefixes `foo/p` and `bar/p`.  These are prefixes, not patterns, so you wouldn't use a `*` at the end.  You also wouldn't put a `/` at the beginning, because in S3 the object keys don't actually begin with `/` (some of the SDKs may hide this fact by allowing object keys to include or omit the leading slash).